# What is the actual usage of @configuration in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I just wanted to know why the below program is working even if I dont use @Configuration annotation on AppConfig class. Can you please let me know how it is working ?

Case 1:

AppConfig.java(with @Configuration)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public Item item(){

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemNo(46789);
        item.setItemName("chair");
        item.setItemType("ART");
        item.setItemSize("A4");
        return item;
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {

    int itemNo;
    String itemName;
    String itemType;
    String itemSize;
    public int getItemNo() {
        return itemNo;
    }
    public void setItemNo(int itemNo) {
        this.itemNo = itemNo;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }
    public void setItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }
    public String getItemSize() {
        return itemSize;
    }
    public void setItemSize(String itemSize) {
        this.itemSize = itemSize;
    }
}
```

ItemTest.java

```
public class ItemTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ct = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Item item = ct.getBean(Item.class);
        System.out.println(item.getItemNo());

    }
}
```

Case 2 :

AppConfig.java ( without @Configuration)

```
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Item item(){

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemNo(46789);
        item.setItemName("chair");
        item.setItemType("ART");
        item.setItemSize("A4");
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the @Configuration annotation from AppConfig  class, calling item() method will be a plain java method call and you will get a **new instance** of Item and it won’t remain **singleton**.

To prove this point, first add a constructor to Item class as following:

```
public class Item {
    ...
    public Item() {
        System.out.println("Item instance created")
    }
    ...
}
```

then define another bean that will be using Item instance as following:

```
public class ItemConsumer {

    public ItemConsumer(Item item) {
        System.out.println("ItemConsumer created");
    }

}
```

and use it as bean in AppConfig class as following:

```
public class AppConfig {


@Bean
public Item item(){
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemNo(46789);
        item.setItemName("chair");
        item.setItemType("ART");
        item.setItemSize("A4");
        return item;
    }

@Bean
public ItemConsumer itemConsumer() {
    return new ItemConsumer(item());
    }
}
```

change ItemTest as below:

```
public class ItemTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ct = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Item item = ct.getBean(Item.class);
        ItemConsumer itemConsumer = ct.getBean(ItemConsumer.class);
    }
}
```

Now when you run the ItemTest class, it generates following output:

```
Item instance created
Item instance created
ItemConsumer created
```

So Item class instantiated twice that means it is not **singleton**.

now annotate AppConfig class with @Configuration annotation again and run the ItemTest class. This time output will be like below:

```
Item instance created
ItemConsumer created
```

Answer (score 2):

### @Bean Lite Mode

> @Bean methods may also be declared within classes that are not
>   annotated with @Configuration. For example, bean methods may be
>   declared in a @Component class or even in a plain old class. In such
>   cases, a @Bean method will get processed in a so-called 'lite' mode.
>
> Bean methods in lite mode will be treated as plain factory methods by
>   the container (similar to factory-method declarations in XML), with
>   scoping and lifecycle callbacks properly applied. The containing class
>   remains unmodified in this case, and there are no unusual constraints
>   for the containing class or the factory methods.

[Source - Spring Documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)